# Eliminar salto de linea al leer archivo txt con java

Tags: java, java-8

**Contexto de la aplicación**

Estoy realizando una aplicación desktop estandar para la empresa, y por ciertas circunstancia .se tiene que manejar unos archivos txt que estos contienen unos códigos para ser consumidos mediante una api rest.

**Contexto del problema**

Estoy teniendo problemas al leer un fichero txt con java, veran al tratar de leer e imprimir me muestra un salto de linea que no esta en el fichero, este es el resultado de leer el archivo:

```
abcd

abcd

abcd

abcd

abcd

abcd

abcd

abcd
```

Estoy aplicando un renplaceAll pero aun asi no me funciona no logro quitar eso, ya que ese archivo cuenta con unos codigos para realizar ciertas acciones los saltos de linea generan error al tratar de ejecutar una funcion, asi es como lo estoy implementando:

```
File codigo = new File("./src/main/java/recurso/codigos.txt");

    FileReader reader = new FileReader(codigo);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String cadena = "";
    while((cadena = br.readLine())!=null){
        cadena = cadena.replaceAll("\n", "");
        System.out.println(cadena);
    }
```

Tengo entendido que en el apartado del `cadena = cadena.replaceAll("\n", "");` me tiene que eliminar el salto de linea pero no lo hace, ademas de eso algunos de los códigos al mostrar lo muestra de la siguiente forma:`ÿþColumm1` cuando tendria que decir ````Column1```

Amigos al tratar de copiar los datos del contenido del archivos codigos a uno nuevo, programa funciona de la forma correcta, este seria el resultado que estoy buscando con el archivo inicial:

```
Column1
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
```

Al parecer es el archivo el cual presenta esos problemas, con esto nuevo que ¿que estara pasando? ¿Tendra alguna solucion? ya que al copiar los archivos seria algo imposible ya que esto son una gran cantidad de código.

**Problema principal al no leer los datos de forma correcta**

Los codigos contenido dentro del txt son usados para hacer ciertos procesos en un api rest, ahora al momento de leer los datos de ese archivo genera un problema, el salto de linea y al parecer una mala lectura de los datos, ya que al pasar los datos resultante de la lectura genera el siguiente error al tratar de consumir la api:

```
Illegal character in query at index 52: http://www.api.com/?apikey=abcsd&plot=full&i=abcde
```

En la url la `ì` es el codigo obtenido de la lectura del archivo, y pues como el mensaje lo muestra la url no es valida al momento de pasar el codigo obtenido del archivo, pero al pasar el contenido a un archivo B recién creado todo estos problemas pasan, lo cual esto **NO ES UNA OPCIÓN** puesto que es una gran cantidad de codigo que pueden ser generados aleatoria mente diariamente ajajaja

**Solución aplicada fallida**

He tratado de aplicar una codificación utf-8 por si eso podría resolver el problema del archivo pero aun así no se ha podido, lo implementado es lo siguiente:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(codigo), "utf-8"));
```

Aun sigue presentando el problema, alguien podría ayudar a dar solución a este gran misterio que tengo

Answer (score 1):

Define un encoding al usar la clase FileReader

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(codigo, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Ademas, estas imprimiendo usando  `System.out.println(...);` , lo que realiza es insertar un salto de linea, debes usar  `System.out.print(...);`

de esta forma el salto de linea extra no se imprimiria

```
 while((cadena = br.readLine())!=null){
        cadena = cadena.replaceAll("\n", "");
        System.out.print(cadena);
    }
```

Comment: Si claro eso lo tengo en claro pero aun asi al aplicar el ```println``` en otros lado no me genera ese salto de linea, ademas al momento de aplicar el resultado me genera un cierto inconveniente, veras tengo que hacer una peticion a una url en base al codigo y pues al copiar el contenido del txt a otro recien creado no me genera problemas y lo muestra como tiene que ser